# How to get an ID from a web service and use it to locate an object

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my app I'm populating a tableview with an array of jobs that I have from a web service. Every job has a specific job ID that I can grab. Now when someone taps a job from the table view, they are brought to the DetailsViewController which displays all the information about that job. So far, my code looks like this to set the job title in the details view controller:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"next"])
{

    NSString *theCorrectUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", theUrlString];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:theCorrectUrlString];

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    NSError *error;

    NSMutableArray *jobsCallArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];


    for (NSDictionary *theJob in jobsCallArray)
    {
        DetailsViewController *detailVC = (DetailsViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;

        NSString *jobPosTitle = theJob[@"position_title"];

        [detailVC  setJobTitleString:jobPosTitle];

    }

    }
}
```

This code however gives me the same job title for every cell. I want to know how I can get the specific job chosen in my table view, and show all of its details on one page.

All help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't make much sense. In this little fragment you're iterating through the array, and you're calling `setJobTitleString` for each object, but obviously whatever this `setJobTitleString` method does, the value is being overwritten and you only see the last value.

```
for (NSDictionary *theJob in jobsCallArray)
{
    DetailsViewController *detailVC = (DetailsViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
    NSString *jobPosTitle = theJob[@"position_title"];
    [detailVC  setJobTitleString:jobPosTitle];
}
```

I can't really tell how to solve this because I don't know what you're trying to do. Retrieving data with `dataWithContentsOfURL` inside `prepareForSegue` is weird, especially because you're retrieving all data, but apparently you only want to show the details for one item.

Comment: Each of my table view cells should have an ID. I just want to grab that ID, and get the contents of each object on my DetailsViewController

Comment: How are you setting this ID?

Comment: Well every cell in my table has one from the web service. It gives it a hidden ID

Comment: Yes but how are you setting the ID to the cell?